# What types do slash command options allow in Pycord?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

In Pycord, a slash command can be defined with arguments that are type-hinted. These type-hints are sent to Discord and Discord figures out how to prompt the user for different types. An example can be seen below:

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.command()
async def ask(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext, question_title: str):
    pass

bot.run('token')
```

Since `question_title` is type-hinted as a string, the user is prompted for a string input.
I want to experiment with other types, but I'm not sure what is available. This information does not seem to be in [Pycord's guide for slash commands](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands)

What types are available for these options?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Pycord docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Option.input_type), the types  of a slash command option can be as follows:

- Primitives like `str`, `int`, `bool`, and `float`
- Channels - either a [`abc.GuildChannel`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) or [`Thread`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Thread)
- "Mentionables", such as a [`Member`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member), [`User`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.User), [`Role`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role), or [`abc.Metionable`]
- An [`Attachment`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment)
- Other types like [`SlashCommandOptionType`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html#discord.SlashCommandOptionType), [`Converter`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Converter) and [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum)